# To access the button on the server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, c#-4.0, devexpress

My Code:

```
<dx:ASPxTreeList ID="treeList" runat = "server">
    <Columns>
      <dx:TreeListDataColumn Name="Edit" FieldName="EditColumn">
        <DataCellTemplate>
          <dx:ASPxButton ID="btnSample" runat="server" Text="SampleText">
          </dx:ASPxButton>
        </DataCellTemplate>
       </dx:TreeListDataColumn>
    </Columns>
    </dx:ASPxTreeList>
```

My goal is to make the button `btnSample` visible to false at `Page_Load`. So, I need to access the `btnSample` id on the server side `Page_Load` event. I don't know how to access the `ID` of the button inside the `TrreListDataColumn` in the server side.

Comment: This button will be displaying in each row.

Comment: When will you need that button visible? Can you set its ClientVisible attribute to false initially and show it when necessary? Do you need to hide all buttons in all rows or just some of them?

Comment: I am having another column called client id.For e.g., For some client ids i neeed to make this button visible to false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle [ASPxTreeList.HtmlDataCellPrepared](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxTreeListASPxTreeList_HtmlDataCellPreparedtopic) event:

```
protected void TreeList_HtmlDataCellPrepared(object sender, TreeListHtmlDataCellEventArgs e)
{
    int empId = (int) e.GetValue("EmpID");
    if ("EditColumn".Equals(e.Column.FieldName) && empId == 1)
    {
        ASPxButton button = (ASPxButton) treeList.FindDataCellTemplateControl(e.NodeKey, e.Column, "btnSample");
        if (button != null)
            button.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `btnSample` returns null since in `viewsource` the id is generated in different format `(i.e) btnsampletdA, btnsampletdAB, etc..` like that and so on. So, I can't able to access the `btnSample` control. I tried for some other alternative like `control.clientID`, then also the `control(btnsample)` is not populated in the list. But other controls outside the `treelist` such as `btnok`,`btncancel` are populated in the `intellisense` and also able to access. Is there any alternative present to access this control which is inside the `DataCellTemplate`.

Comment: I created sample project and code I posted works correctly. Have you tested it without additional condition ( && <your ClientID condition> )? When you remove it all buttons should be hidden.

Comment: I am getting `ASPxButton button` as null value

Comment: I am posting my `cs` code. Please see to that.`protected void treeList_OnHtmlDataCellPrepared(object sender, TreeListHtmlDataCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if ("EmpID".Equals(e.Column.FieldName) && e.CellValue.ToString() == "1")
            {
                ASPxButton button = (ASPxButton)treeList.FindDataCellTemplateControl(e.NodeKey, e.Column, "btnShowPopup");
                if (button != null)
                    button.Visible = false;
            }
        }`

Comment: `btnShowPopup` in `viewsource` displaying as `treeList_tDC11_1_btnShowPopup',`treeList_tDC11_1_btnShowPopup_B`,`treeList_tDC11_1_btnShowPopup_CD, `etc..`, as it is generating random `id's` wherever the `btnShowPopup` is displayed in the `treelist`

Comment: Can you posto your markup too? It's easier to post it as update to your initial answer.

Comment: I had edited my question and posted the full code. Please see to that.

Comment: You are fetching templated button if column fieldName equals EmpID but your dataitemtemplate is  declared in column with fieldName EditPopup. So, change "EmpId".Equals(e.Column.FieldName)... to "EditPopup.Equals"....

Comment: Yes. Now it is recognizing the `btnShowPopup` control, but I need to check another condition along with `("EditPopup".Equals(e.Column.FieldName))` `(i.e),` `EmpID` also. As of now for testing the `btnShowPopup` I used only `if ("EditPopup".Equals(e.Column.FieldName))`. How to add `EmpID` as a condition along with that because I tried `if ("EditPopup".Equals(e.Column.FieldName) && e.CellValue.ToString() == "1")`, it is throwing `Object reference` error.

Comment: Thanks a Lot. You guide me very well to achieve my goal. I appreciate your patience first of all. It was working fine as I expected. Once again, I am Thanking You for your wonderful solution. Great.